# Visual Studio 2010 Express - Disabling Debug Event Handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express to debug a DirectX application(in which the message loop processes a single frame of animation for each iteration). By default, the debug engine handles the 'exit thread'(EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT) event. Because my application implements multithreading, this event occurs multiple times per frame(iteration of the message loop) and handling of the event slows down my application. This is undesirable...

Is there a way to disable a single debug event handler without having to create and attach a custom debug engine?

```
I know that I can disable the output to the debug window by doing the following:

On the Tools menu, click Options.
In the Options dialog box, select the Debugging node.
Under the expanded Debugging node, select the Output Window entry.

Under General Output Settings on the right hand side of the Options window, change 'Thread Exit Messages' from 'On' to 'Off'

Click OK
```

The debug engine, however, continues to handle the event and the application continues to run slowly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the original question has not been answered yet, I have found a solution to the problem. My implementation of multithreading was improper. Instead of creating a new thread each frame for each asynchronous method(my original implementation) I create the threads one time during application initialization and use wait handles(System.Threading.AutoResetEvent) and flow control in the form of a 'while' loop to rerun each asynchronous method. Here is a sample:

```
public static class State
{
    AutoResetEvent _renderOpsWH,
        _recordWH;
    Thread _recordThread;
    int _ncAsyncOps;
    bool _runThreads;
    ...
}

public static void Initialize()
{
    _renderOpsWH = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    _recordWH = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    _recordThread = new Thread(Record) { Name = "Recording Device" };
    _recordThread.Start();
}

public static void Render()
{
    State._ncAsyncOps = 1;

    // signal the 'record' wait handle -- this will allow one execution of the Record method
    State._recordWH.Set();

    // 
    // Other work is done here
    //

    // wait for all render operations to finish before proceeding
    State._renderOpsWH.WaitOne();

    // present scene
}

public static void Record()
{
    // State._runThreads is a boolean variable that when false will allow the thread to terminate(simply by exiting the method Record)
    while (State._runThreads)
    {
        // wait for the Render method signal(this controls the execution of this thread)
        State._recordWH.WaitOne();

        // record the current frame
        SceneManager.Record(State._pd3dRecorder[State._niRecorder], GetBackBufferSurfaceDesc());

        // decrement the count of asynchronous operations. If the count is 0 then signal the wait handle found in the Render method in order to continue with the frame
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref State._ncAsyncOps) == 0)
            State._renderOpsWH.Set();
    }
}

public static void Dispose()
{
// set false to break the 'while' loop containing the 'record' thread
State._runThreads = false;

// signal the 'record' wait handle to allow the final execution of the 'record' thread
State._recordWH.Set();
}
```